# Mailchimp - 405 Method not allowed

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Have an existing API that suddenly stopped working. `GuzzleHttp` is used in this project.
Cannot delete users over an API with Mailchimp. Response;

`405 Method Not Allowed response: {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Method Not Allowed", "st (truncated...) in vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113`

Here is my code;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new Client([
        'auth' => ['bread', getenv('MAILCHIMP_API_KEY'), 'basic'],
    ]);
}

public function delete_member_from_list(string $member_email, string $list_id): ResponseInterface
{
    $subscriber_hash = $this->get_subscriber_hash($member_email);
    // Just making sure vars are defined and they are
    error_log('List id: ' . $list_id);
    error_log('Hash: ' . $subscriber_hash);

    return $this->client->delete("{$this->endpoint}/lists/{$list_id}/members/{$subscriber_hash}");
}
```

Mailchimp [documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/error-glossary/#405) states: `This error means that the requested resource does not support the HTTP method you used.`

And this is from the [API documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/) for deleting a member from a list;

[image: Mailchimmp API[3]

And finally from Guzzle;

[image: guzzle]

So it seems as the http method is right but Mailchimp still returning 405.

Thanks in advance.

Info;

- PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Aug 12 2019 19:34:28) ( NTS
  )
- SSL

Comment: Update; I got this message on Mailchimp dashboard: `This list member cannot be removed. Please contact support.`

Comment: Experiencing this today, but in RoR. Any news so far?

Comment: @RicardoGreen not yet. Client has a free plan so cannot contact support. But I suspect there has been a change with their API.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Yeah must have been because of the API and pricing updates. What's actually happening on our end is that the records are being `archived` instead of `deleted` when you run the delete call and then it returns that same error.

Comment: Same for Python client.